# What does the bolded part of the sentence mean?

Tags: meaning

Giving medicine to relieve suffering, even if it risks or causes death, is not assisted suicide or euthanasia; nor is withdrawing treatments that only prolong a painful dying process. Like the general public, many in the medical profession are not clear about these distinctions. Terms like assisted death or death with dignity blur these distinctions, **implying that a special law is necessary to make such practices legal-in most countries they already are.**

Comment: What are you having trouble with? the meanings of the words? the use of a "dash"?

Comment: I don't understand the context after the dash. Is he implying that these practices are already legal?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about understanding basic English

Comment: He is stating that these practices are, indeed, legal in some countries--Belgium is a case in point.@curious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot understand the bolded part without the unbolded part. The bolded part is stating that the existence of the terms "assisted death" and "death with dignity" reveal a misunderstanding of what was explained earlier. That misunderstanding is what is claimed to be the root for the need for special laws to legalize those practices. Those practices are already legal in most places.